# Java Spring - MySQL timestamp field and millisecond precision

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm trying to store some time information in MySQL database with millisecond precision. The format that I want to store is `2015-08-13 10:56:24.570` like that.

The problem is, I have to create table column with length attributes (3 or 6, depends on fractional part). The application that I wrote with Java Spring Framework automatically creates mysql table if it isn't created before. But I can't set the length attributes of date field.

"`@Column` annotation has the length argument but it only considerable with String fields." says the document of Spring Jpa.

Another interesting part is I couldn't use `@Temporal` annotation. My IDE gives an error that "The annotation `@Temporal` is disallowed for this location". I wonder why I given this error also.

Any help would be great for me.

EDIT: My Java code for creating mysql table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dbTable")
public class Report
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "myDate", nullable = false, length = 6)
    private java.util.Date date;

    // Getters Setters etc.

}
```

Comment: What is the type of that column you are using ?

Comment: and post the entity ...

Comment: I tried "DATE,DATETIME,TIMESTAMP". As long as I don't add the length attribute, it doesn't saves the fractional part (millisecond).  @AmitBhati

Comment: Are you using the TimeStamp of java.sql package because its default format do consider millisecond precision.

Comment: The problem is not to generate millisecond precision formatted time information, the problem is to store them.

Answer (score 1):

Make the column of type

> java.sql.Timestamp

while storing the time related information in MySQL.

Simple Example:-

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2013-10-10 10:49:29.12000"));
}

Output:- 2013-10-10 10:49:29.12
```

[Read this](http://www.developerscrappad.com/228/java/java-ee/ejb3-jpa-dealing-with-date-time-and-timestamp/), if it helps.

Change  the column type to java.sql.Timestamp from java.util.Timestamp.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right, I can create my time information like that. But when I try to store it in MySQL database, is saves "2013-10-10 10:49:29".

Comment: Paste your Entity class which your inserting into MySQL db in your question.

Comment: i think you need to change the DB column Data type .

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is kind of an old post, but I had the same problem and figured out a way around it. Here's what my entity looked like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ActivityLog")
public class ActivityLogBean {
    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date alDateTime;
}
```

I was getting the error message "The annotation @Temporal is disallowed for this location" on the "@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)" line.

The problem had to do with which Temporal class I was importing, and the import statement that I was using when I had the problem was:

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Temporal;

I changed the import to the following, and the error went away:

import javax.persistence.Temporal;

Here's my full working class now:

```
package com.mypackage.beans;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ActivityLog")
public class ActivityLogBean {
    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date alDateTime;
}
```